# How do you create a new formula?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e, crafting

One of my players is an Inventor, and has come up with some ideas for brand-new magical and mundane items. I've found guidance on how to homebrew magical items, and I feel pretty confident on our ability to come up with balanced homebrew, so that part's not an issue. And I know that he can use his Inventor feat to create common formulas that he doesn't already know, but since these are brand-new items I can hardly call them common formulas. I've looked through a bunch of the crafting rules and I can't find anything that specifically tells me how a player can create their own new formulas in play.

Are there rules for how to make new formulas for new items? If not, how have you addressed this problem in the past?

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for rules on them coming up with the forumla (an in-game item about how to make another item) or homebrew items?

Comment: Added a clarifying line, I'm specifically asking for how to create the formula for a homebrew item, I've been able to find good guidance on how to make homebrew items. Just not the formulas for them.

Answer (score 5):

## You give the Inventor access

If you know how to [homebrew items](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1053), and how the Inventor uses the [Inventor feat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=798) to craft the [formula](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=250) for a common item, then all you're missing is an understanding of [rarity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=914):

> The rarity system is a powerful tool that helps you and your group customize your story, your characters, and your world to better match your game’s themes and setting. You can also use it to keep the complexity of your game low by limiting access to unusual options.

Rarity is a tool that exists to help you customize and manage your world, and **it certainly doesn't exist to stop you, the GM, from doing anything!**
So lets say that these soon-to-be-invented homebrew items are Rare or maybe even Unique, makes perfect sense. What comes next is extremely simple:

> - **Rare** elements are lost secrets, ancient magic, and other **options that PCs can access only if you specifically make them available.**
> - **Unique** elements are one of a kind. **You have full control over whether PCs can access them.** Named NPCs are unique creatures, though that doesn’t mean their base creature type is unique. For instance, an orc named Graytusk is unique, but that doesn’t mean it would be any harder for a PC encountering her to tell she’s an orc—just to discern specific information about her.

You just grant the Inventor access to those homebrew items, because that's exactly the kind of decision that rarity empowers you with.

---

As a side note, the exact meaning of "access" is not well defined. The closest definition I could find is for the [access entry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=917):

> Uncommon elements sometimes have an Access entry in their stat block. A character who meets the specifications listed there **has access to that option just like they would to a common option**, even though it’s uncommon. These entries include a statement such as “follower of Shelyn,” “member of the Pathfinder Society,” or “from Absalom.”

We can infer that access granted by the GM can do at least as much as an access entry, *rarity is a GM's tool afterall*. So to be extra pendantic, what you need to grant to the Inventor is "access to those homebrew items as though they were common, for the purpose of the Inventor feat".